# Want to remove the <br type="_moz"> tag in CKEDITOR 4.2.0

Tags: ckeditor

With the inline editor CKEDITOR 4.2.0 and Firefox 23.0.1 the inner html of my editable div tags are enriched with `<br type="_moz">`. It is not inserted with IE.

I can easily find and replace this tag using javascript.

How can I handle this in the config.js file globally for all my inline editable divs?

Comment: That sounds like a filler element inserted automatically by Firefox, but it should be filtered out by CKEditor when you call the getData method. Doesn't that work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **should not** get data from inline editor by `element.innerHTML` (or `$(element).html()`). There's a significant difference between what's really in there and what will CKEditor returns from `editor.getData()` (which is the correct method to use).

This difference comes from the fact that data (set by `editor.setData()` - yup - don't set it directly too) needs to be transformed to be better editable inside `contenteditable` element. Therefore, then that transformation (and other weird things done by/for browsers) need to be reverted and this happens on `editor.getData()`.

PS. If you don't know where to get editor instances check global `CKEDITOR.instances` object.

Comment: getData() does put the string from the inner html into HTML entities. e.g. ö becomes &ouml; How do you deal with that? Save the as unicode and output as unicode? My DB is set to UTF-8.

Comment: See [config.entities_lating](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-entities_latin) and [config.entities_greek](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-entities_greek).

Answer (score 1):

If using jQuery you can simply search the document for < br type="_moz" > and remove it. Of course you don't need to search whole document, just the DOM element you want.

```
$(document).find('br').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('type') === '_moz'){
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: one liner: `$('br[type=_moz]').remove()`

Answer (score 1):

Quick easy CSS solution would be to add the following to your stylesheet that gets loaded into CKeditor:

```
br[type="_moz"]{display: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this patch and it worked for me.

http://dev.ckeditor.com/attachment/ticket/5767/5767.patch

Unfortunately, ckeditor team did not use this patch.

So remove `appendBogus` function from _`source/core/dom/element.js` and add new `appendBogus` function  to `_source/core/dom/walker.js` and then combine all the js file as per `ckeditor.pack` file to recreate ckeditor.js