# CKEditor: with widget as first element, select all not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

If you add a widget as first element, Ctrl+A will not work in Chrome. If some text is added before, the "select all" works perfectly.

Any workaround?

i'am using ckeditor 4.5.5.

try on [Widget Demo](https://cksource.com/temp/widget/samples/plugins/widget/widget.html).

*NB: in Firefox the Ctrl+A works, but a tag `<br type="_moz"></br>` is added in the first widget.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A problem with selecting content in Blink or WebKit browsers when the widget is the first or last element in the editable area is a known issue and has been reported here: https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/11180. As you can see in the ticket report, we were also able to reproduce this problem in native `contenteditable` elements what indicates a browser bug. Unfortunately we weren't able to find any workaround for this problem and browser vendors haven't provided a fix yet.

---

**NOTES:**

- Widget demo can be found here: https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/simplebox.html. The link you have provided is an old widget preview which is using CKEditor 4.1 (widgets were officially introduced in CKEditor 4.3).
- These `br's` you mention are inserted by Firefox. There is nothing to worry about as they will be filtered out once you obtain the data from the editor using the [`editor.getData`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-getData) method. Here is a good general explanation of how it works: [Want to remove the <br type="_moz"> tag in CKEDITOR 4.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469969/want-to-remove-the-br-type-moz-tag-in-ckeditor-4-2-0)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I suspected something like that. Maybe automaticly added a empty tag before widget if it's first element could be a acceptable workaround.